# Initializing and returning the tableau and foundation in python

Tags: python

There is a problem that I am having trouble with. I am having trouble initializing and returning the tableau, and foundation. the foundation is a list of 4 empty lists and tableau is a list of 7 lists. The deck is shuffled and then all cards dealt to the tableau.

```
def init_game():
  foundation = [1, 4]
  tableau = [1, 7]
  pass
  return tableau, foundation
```

For some reason it does seem to work and I don't know where the error could be

Comment: To me you're just initializing two lists. And returning both. I get a tuple of two lists as a return when calling the function so there's nothing weird to me. What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? do you get any error message?

Comment: Delete "pass". You are not returning the values.